# Render Divs with DataSet content including Columns

Tags: html, asp.net, css, vb.net

I am struggling to render my DataSet contents into DIV tags with column names as headers.

I am trying to get it within a structure like so:

```
<div class="dataset">
        <div class="dsheader">
           <div class="dscell"><h6>Staff Name</h6></div>
           <div class="dscell"><h6>Accrued Hours</h6></div>
           <div class="dscell"><h6>Date Accrued</h6></div>
        </div>

        <div class="dsrow">
            <div class="dscell"><p>1</p></div>
            <div class="dscell"><p>2</p></div>
            <div class="dscell"><p>3</p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"/>             
</div>
```

I have no idea how to start so I started the easy way and rendered the data into a table:

```
  Dim r As DataRow
    Dim dvCont As New HtmlGenericControl
    Dim dvHead As New HtmlGenericControl
    Dim dvRow As New HtmlGenericControl
    Dim dvCell As HtmlGenericControl


    For i As Integer = 0 To DataTable.Rows.Count - 1

        Dim myRow As New HtmlTableRow
        Dim divrow As New HtmlGenericControl
        Dim divcell As New HtmlGenericControl
        Dim StaffMemberCell As New HtmlTableCell
        Dim LieuTypeCell As New HtmlTableCell
        Dim LieuDateCell As New HtmlTableCell
        Dim LieuDetailsCell As New HtmlTableCell

        StaffMemberCell.InnerHtml = DataTable.Rows(i).Item("staff_member").ToString
        myRow.Cells.Add(StaffMemberCell)

        LieuTypeCell.InnerHtml = DataTable.Rows(i).Item("lieu_type").ToString
        myRow.Cells.Add(LieuTypeCell)

        LieuDateCell.InnerHtml = DataTable.Rows(i).Item("lieu_date").ToString
        myRow.Cells.Add(LieuDateCell)

        LieuDetailsCell.InnerHtml = DataTable.Rows(i).Item("lieu_details").ToString
        myRow.Cells.Add(LieuDetailsCell)

        lieuTable.Rows.Add(myRow)
    Next
```

Where do I go from here?
I know to add `runat="server"` to DIV tags on the ASPX page.

```
 <div id="dvContainer" class="dataset" runat="server">
    <div id="dvContHeader" class="dsheader" runat="server">
        <div id="dvContCell" class="dscell" runat="server"><h6>Header</h6></div>
        <div id="Div1" class="dscell" runat="server"><h6>Header</h6></div>
        <div id="Div2" class="dscell" runat="server"><h6>Header</h6></div>
    </div>

    <div id="dvRow" class="dsrow" runat="server"><p>data1</p></div>
        <div id="dvContCell" class="dsrow" runat="server"><p>data1</p></div>
        <div id="Div4" class="dsrow" runat="server"><p>data1</p></div>
        <div id="Div5" class="dsrow" runat="server"><p>data1</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another issue I have is do I have to explicitly state the div within the ASPX doc? See below. I see an issue with using the ID tags multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the result I was looking for by using a repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

<HeaderTemplate>
    <div class="dsDataSet">
            <div class="dsheader">
                <div class="dscell"><h6>Staff Name</h6></div>
                <div class="dscell"><h6>Accrued Hours</h6></div>
                <div class="dscell"><h6>Date Accrued</h6></div>
            </div>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
            <div class="dsrow">
                <div class="dscell"><p><%# Eval("Staff_member")%></p></div>
                <div class="dscell"><p><%# Eval("Num_Hours")%></p></div>
                <div class="dscell"><p><%# Format(Eval("Lieu_Date"), "dd-MM-yyyy")%></p></div>
            </div>

</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
        <div class="clearfix"/>
    </div>  
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```